# Monix write to single output stream from parallel Tasks

Tags: scala, stream, task, monix

how can we use Monix Tasks to write a single output stream from a sequence of tasks (can run in parallel):
for example, I have N tasks that can be run in parallel and get some response from `HTTP call/server,` and I'm writing the response back to a file stream (as is there constraint Limited memory) but
I get the `stream closed error,` was wondering if there is a way to achieve this using Monix tasks or any other API

```
java.io.IOException: Stream closed
```

Sample Code snippet:

```
 import java.io.{FileOutputStream, OutputStream, OutputStreamWriter}

    import monix.eval.Task
    import monix.execution.ExecutionModel.AlwaysAsyncExecution
    import monix.execution.Scheduler

    import scala.util.Random

    object TaskTest extends App {

      implicit val scheduler = Scheduler(
        AlwaysAsyncExecution
      )
      val list = List(1 to 100)

      val filePath = System.currentTimeMillis() + "_test.txt"
      val outputStreamWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(filePath))
      val futureTask = autoClose(outputStreamWriter) {
        outputStream =>
          val totalCount = SeqOfTasks(outputStream)
          totalCount.map(_.sum)
      }

      futureTask.runToFuture.onComplete {
        case scala.util.Success(value) =>
          println(s"fetched a total of $value")

        case scala.util.Failure(exception) =>

          println("there is some error occurred ")
          println(exception)
      }

//close this stream when all tasks completed.
      def autoClose[A <: AutoCloseable, B](resource: A)(code: A ⇒ B): B = {
        try code(resource)
        finally resource.close()
      }


      def SeqOfTasks(outPutStream: OutputStreamWriter): Task[Seq[Int]] = {

        val list = List(0 to 10: _*)
        Task.wanderUnordered(list)(l => makeHttpCall(outPutStream, l))
      }

      // each taks will fetch some data and write to single out put stream that is shared by other tasks.
      def makeHttpCall(outputStream: OutputStreamWriter, value: Int): Task[Int] = {

        Task {
          val result = getDummyValue(value)
          val bytes = result.mkString("\t") + "\n"
          outputStream.write(bytes)
          //return some value
          result.size
        }
      }

      //return a dummy response for http
      def getDummyValue(n: Int): Seq[Int] = {
        println(s"dummy value : $n")
        Seq.fill(n)(Random.nextInt)
      }
```

Comment: Technical question aside, are you aware that this will not work? Having multiple asynchronous processes write into a single `OutputStream` will result in garbled data, because it happens character by character. What you want to do is write each response in a different file.

Comment: Hi Markus,

The output stream is sync and thread-safe, so it will not result in garbled data and output is being to streamed to cloud storage and requires data written to a single file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is due to `Task` is being Lazy and async, but `autoClose` is neither.

The solution is to make autoClose Task-aware:

```
def autoClose[A <: AutoCloseable, B](resource: A)(code: A ⇒ Task[B]): Task[B] = {
    code(resource).guarantee(Task(resource.close()))
  }
```

**Note: This is answered by [Oleg Pyzhcov](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2758343/oleg-pyzhcov) on [Monix Gitter chat](https://gitter.im/monix/monix?at=5d0b029c4291ad76a58f11f6)**